# Animation isn't playing after I specify which frames to play

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I've started trying to make a game with kaboom.js and have come across a problem where the animation for an arrow which flashes isn't playing, it just freeze frames at the first frame. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

### **The Code**

```
const k = kaboom({
width: 320,
height: 240,
scale: 2,
});

k.loadSprite("selArrow", "sprites/selArrow.png", {
  sliceX: 2,
  sliceY: 2,
  anims: {
    main: { 
      from: 0, 
      to: 3,
      speed: 2,
      loop: true}
}});
```

```
const selArrow = k.add([
  k.sprite("selArrow", {anim: "main"}),
  k.pos(50),
  k.scale(1.5),
  k.origin("center"),
]);
```

**The Spritesheet**

[image: The Spritesheet]